# Drupal CKEditor module remove line breaks

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I have legacy content that has line breaks as paragraph separator. When trying to deal with them using [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module 7.x-1.16 and CKEditor 4.5.4 library, all line breaks  are removed and the text turned into an ugly mass of text.

I tried disabling some filters from the *Full HTML* input format:

1. Limit allowed HTML tags
2. Convert line breaks into HTML
3. Correct faulty and chopped off HTML

I also tried to use custom formatting options and disabling _Advanced content filter. In any case, I didn't achieve my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simply in two points:

1. Adding the following config to in the advanced option tab of the desired profile:
   `admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full`

   config.protectedSource = [/\r|\n/g];

This will keep the source of the content with new lines as it is and forget about its shape in the wysiwyg.

2. In for the container that holds your content, use the following css rule:

   white-space: pre-line;
   This will keep lines separated as paragraphs.

checkout those screen shots:

Add the protected source config:
[image]

Don't worry about it in wysiwyg:
[image]

Just look at the source:
[image]

It will look like the following on the frontend:

[image]

> Don't forget to flush cache specially if you optimized and aggregate
>   js and css, also remove your browser cache or enabling remove cache
>   during using dev tools (chrome)

Comment: Assalam-o-alaykum. This bug seems to be removed in drupal 7.54. Tested it on long text textarea field which I was having problem when using 7.50. Yet to test with better formats. Hope it has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

[Wysiwyg Linebreaks](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_linebreaks)

> You can choose between two different methods:
>
> - Force linebreaks: Your content will always preserve    whitespace/linebreaks around blocks of text, rather than paragraph
>     and break tags.
> - Convert linebreaks: Your legacy content will appear correctly in your    WYSIWYG editor, then the content will be saved with the markup
>     added    by the editor).

Comment: There is a big problem in your solution for me, as I regarded, I use CKEditor module (stand alone) not the Wysiwyg module.

Comment: in ck editor only convert br option convert into HTML if you change text editor then you able to solve your problem