# Ckeditor removing line breaks

Tags: wysiwyg

CKEditor was initially working correctly. Now it's removing all the line breaks and the font size and color changes in my text.

The source code still shows

, , , and

tags (with closing tags), but even the list does not begin on a new line. When I format a line as a headline, it gets smashed together with all the other text.

I followed all the steps posted by 
sємsєм
201112 at [Drupal CKEditor module remove line breaks](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/177680/drupal-ckeditor-module-remove-line-breaks), but the problem was not solved.

I know html well, but I'm not skilled with css or php. Can I solve this by inserting css styles into the source code? Since the editor worked correctly earlier, I think I must be missing something. 
Thanks.

Comment: which Drupal version?